# How to make a Rigidbody2D bullet move in Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying various fixes for days now and I cannot figure this out. I need a bullet to spawn and move until collision, but I cannot even get it to move (it spawns just fine). Note: This is a 2D game.
Here is my code:

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float timeBetweenFire = 2;
    public Rigidbody2D bullet;
    public Transform gunSpawn;
    private float timer;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {   
        timer+=Time.deltaTime;
        if (timer >= timeBetweenFire) {
            Shoot();
            timer = 0;
        }
    }

    private void Shoot() {
        Rigidbody2D bulletInstance;
        bulletInstance = Instantiate(bullet, gunSpawn.position, gunSpawn.rotation) as Rigidbody2D;
        //bulletInstance.AddForce(gunSpawn.forward * 1000f);
        //bulletInstance.AddForce(Vector3.up * 10 * Time.deltaTime);
        //bulletInstance.AddForce(transform.forward * 100);
        bulletInstance.AddForce(Vector3.up * 1000);
    }
}
```

The commented bulletInstance methods are what I've recently tried, I did a bunch of large scale code changes regarding bullet (iirc changed it around between Rigidbody, GameObject, and Transform) and nothing helped. The bullet spawns a good bit away from anything except the gunSpawn, which is just an empty GameObject, so I don't think collisions are an issue. I'm a new Unity programmer so forgive me for any dumb mistakes.

UPDATE:
This is what I did to get it (mostly) working. When the bullet collides it can spin out, but at least I made *some* progress.

```
public class Deflect : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D bullet;
    public float bulletSpeed = 0.1f;
    Vector2 direction = new Vector3(0.7f,0.7f);
    ContactPoint2D[] myContact = new ContactPoint2D[1];
     Vector2 _velocity;
    public void Update ()
    {
    }


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        bullet = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();


        _velocity = bullet.velocity;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        foreach (ContactPoint2D contact in collision.contacts)
        {
            print(contact.collider.name + " hit " + contact.otherCollider.name);
            // Visualize the contact point
            Debug.DrawRay(contact.point, contact.normal, Color.white);
        }

        Vector2 inNormal = collision.contacts[0].normal;
        _velocity = Vector3.Reflect(_velocity, inNormal);
        bullet.velocity = _velocity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `isKinematic` enabled on the prefabs `Rigidbody2D`? I wouldn't use force here. You always have to take the bullets' mass into account. Rather directly set a fix velocity: `bulletInstance.velocity = ...` then also note that `Vector3.up` is a global direction.. if you want to be depending on the `gunSpawn`'s rotation you should use e.g. `bulletInstance.velocity = gunSpawn.up * bulletVelocity;`

Answer (score 1):

1 - Create your bullet prefab as a `GameObject`
2 - Add a `RigidBody2D` to it
3 - Make sure the isKinematic is unchecked on the `Rigibody2d`
4 - then
`GameObject bulletInstance = Instantiate(bullet, gunSpawn.position,gunSpawn.rotation);
 bulletInstance.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector3.up * 1000);`

---

IsKinematic prevents the `Rigidbody2D` to be affected by forces .
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html

Comment: When I try to use the code you suggested it says "Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D' to 'UnityEngine.GameObject'"

Comment: Declare your bullet a GameObject instead of Rigidbody2D and everything should be fine. Make sure to follow the steps I metnioned before the code

Comment: @mahdi OP should rather go the other way round and declare both `bullet` and `bulletInstance` as `Rigidbody2D` .. otherwise `bulletInstance.AddForce` will fail ... But I presume that is somehow what OP already did originally, right? ;)

Comment: woopsie my bad! I will edit my response I forgot the .GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>()

Comment: I updated the question with what I have right now. So far it deflects at the right angle, just spinning a bit. Is there a way to prevent physics from affecting rotation? Would disabling that mean I need to calculate the rotation myself?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the bullet has a rigid-body component and that it is not set to kinematic.

Comment: Is Dynamic or Static preferred?

Comment: When working with forces, dynamic is the way to go. Dynamic bodies will behave as expected in a physics simulation (finite mass, etc). Static bodies will not move during simulation, as if they have infinite mass.

Comment: Here is the documentation on this topic: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody2D.html